# PostgreSQL to Power BI Dax

Tags: sql, postgresql, powerbi, dax

I am currently trying to convert a SQL-command to Power-BI DAX, because I need this to be a calculated table. The imported data is really big and calculating on the result of a query is required.

In this command, grouping, filtering and adding columns with conditions is required and I am not sure how to nest those commands.

To summarize my intentions:
I am trying to group my result by c1, c2 and c3, add a column "Start" with the MIN datetime of the grouped entries, add another column with the MAX datetime of the grouped entries as "End", count the number of entries per group and count the number of entries per group with a condition.
At the end I am filtering the whole query on another column by terminating false states with state >=0.

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, MIN(datetime) AS Start, MAX(datetime) AS End, COUNT(*) AS NewColumn1, COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE state=1) AS NewColumn2
FROM table
WHERE state>= 0
GROUP BY c1, c2, c3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
CALCULATETABLE(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'table'
            ,'table'[c1],'table'[c2],'table'[c3]
        )
        ,"Start", CALCULATE(MIN('table'[datetime]))
        ,"End", CALCULATE(MAX('table'[datetime]))
        ,"NewColumn1", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('table'))
        ,"NewColumn2", CALCULATE(
                            COUNTROWS('table')
                           --,ALL('table')
                           ,'table'[state]=1
                       )
    )
    ,'table'[state]>= 0
)
```

Comment: would be nice to have a feedback

Comment: I fear it does not work. The Columns "Start", "End" show the MIN and MAX value of the whole dataset, not the specific summarized group. The same thing is happening to "NewColumn1" and "NewColumn2". Both columns show the same value, the overall value of the table and not the group by value.

Comment: check the altered answer

Comment: Thank you, yes the altered answer worked just fine!